# Unable to create folder in android internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm trying to create a folder in the internal storage of the phone but it just doesn't create it no matter what i do

Things I've tried:

- unplugging the phone from the computer
- set permissions both in manifest and programatically for API 23+
- every single variation of folder getting i could find:
  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
  Environment.getDataDirectory()
  etc..
- searched every single article or variation of the article for similar problems
- tried both variations of mkdir() and mkdirs()
- checked phone if folder exists

This code is also tied to a button so the permission asking should already be granted the second time i press it.

```java
File sdir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getpath(), "/DBTEST/");

String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, 1);

System.out.println("DIRECTORY CREATED: " + sdir.mkdirs());
System.out.println("EXISTS: " + sdir.exists());
```

```
System.out: DIRECTORY CREATED: false
System.out: EXISTS: false
```

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testM">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: There is no code that tries to create a directory.

Comment: Have a look at sdir.mkdir() and sdir.mkdirs().

Comment: yes, i've tied both variations of mkdir and mkdirs and none of them work :/

Comment: You should post complete code of course.

Comment: `System.out.println("DIRECTORY CREATED: " + sdir.mkdirs());` That will return false if the directory alreay existst. Only call mkdir() and mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet.

Comment: "checked phone if folder exists" -- you may not see an empty directory except via programming tools (e.g., Device File Explorer in Android Studio). Note that you do not have access to this storage on Android 10 (by default) or Android R+ (for all apps), so you might want to consider doing something else anyway.

Comment: `File sdir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getpath(), "/DBTEST/");` That should be `File sdir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DBTEST");`

Comment: Please tell the (old) value of sdir.getAbsolutePath(). And the new one.

Comment: i'm checking if it exists with  sdir.exists() as shown in the code

Comment: absolute path is /storage/emulated/0/DBTEST

Comment: Well i asked for two values... Did you ever get the permission? Go to the settings for your app and look if the Storage toggle is on on. You can put it on on manually.

Comment: yes i did, permission is granted and i did try without the getpath as well

Comment: What is the target SDK Version are you using? Is it 29? Does android studio give you a deprecation warning for getExternalStorageDirectory()?

Comment: target version is 15 and no i don't get a deprecation warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

`File sdir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getpath(), "/DBTEST/");`

to

`File sdir = new File (Environment.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/DBTEST/");`

According to the developer docs:

> getExternalStorageDirectory() -
>   This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

`getExternalFilesDir(null)` will return your apps storage folder at (Internal Storage)/Android/data/your.app.name/file/

If you want to access certain OS defined folders you just pass environmental constants defined here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

and here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment

under the "Fields" section.

Ex. downloads would be: `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

Comment: I did, would you happen to know how to access the downloads or general storage folder then instead of just being able to access your app data folder?

Comment: Updated my answer to include that!

Comment: i did actually try that and it doesn't access the device downloads folder, it just makes a downloads folder inside your app This PC\Pixel 2 XL\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.example.testM\files\Download\DBTEST

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. Tested in my dummy app with same results as yours. Have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

This is a privacy restriction introduced in Android-Q. Direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated when an app targets API 29 and the path returned from [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Use the app-specific directory to write & read files.

*By default, apps targeting Android 10 and higher are given [scoped access into external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped), or scoped storage. Such apps can see the following types of files within an external storage device without needing to request any storage-related user permissions:*

- Files in the app-specific directory, accessed using [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).
- Photos, videos, and audio clips that the app created from the [media store](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/media).